# Can't upload file with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, upload, xmlhttprequest

I want to upload a file in background using JavaScript and `XMLHttpRequest` but my page "upload.php" receive empty $_POST and $_FILES.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", file);
xhr.open("POST", "upload.php", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control','no-cache');
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","multipart/form-data");     
xhr.send(formData);
```

I have try a lot a things in `xhr.setRequestHeader()` but nothings work.

Comment: @Machavity Since this question doesn't mention [tag:jquery] or appear to use it, I wouldn't count this as a duplicate of that particular Q&A, at least.

Comment: What is the value of `file`, in this case? Also, have you tried without setting the headers manually? `.send()` will already set some headers just from being given `FormData`.

Comment: `file` is a file object from an input `<input type="file" />` I just tried withouth setting the header, the result is the same.

Comment: the file name is missing, not sure if that matters...

Comment: Iin the header settings ? I have tried but it doesn't work too

Comment: xhr.send only works when the parameter is a File object, not a FormData think. So I use jquery $.ajax, which allows post form data and files at the same time